# Special tag for UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, tags, uibutton

I have 3 different UIButtons for each image grouped. I have IDs for each image. Right now, I have a special id for each image, and I set the button with that tag.

I want to change the background image of the one selected when you tap it. The problem is, is that 3 buttons have the same tag so I cannot change the right button's background image.

Here's what I have:

```
UIButton *likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[likeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_like_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_like_button_hit.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_like_button_hit.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_like_button_hit.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[likeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(13, 52 + (285 * count), 51, 55)];
[likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeDudle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[likeButton setTag:theIdInt];
[likeButton setTitle:@"no_like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[scrollView addSubview:likeButton];

- (IBAction)likeDudle: (id)sender {

NSInteger tagId = ((UIControl*)sender).tag;

UIButton *tempButton = (UIButton*)[scrollView viewWithTag:tagId];

NSLog(@"likeDudle: %d // %@", tagId, tempButton.titleLabel.text);

if ([tempButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"no_like"]) {
    [tempButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_like_button_hit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton setTitle:@"like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if ([tempButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"like"]) {
    [tempButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_like_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton setTitle:@"no_like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Is there a better way in doing this?

Thanks,
Coulton

Comment: Why not give each button a unique tag?

Comment: It's all done from a server and each image gets a unique id. there is one button for each. so if i gave them different ids, it wouldn't match up with the correct image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fewer than 10 images, then give the `i`th button the tag `i*10+image.tag`. Then you can retrieve the `image.tag` by `button.tag % 10` and the button tags will be unique. You can even retrieve the button only information by `int b = button.tag/10`.

Also, you can access the button's image's tag with `button.backgroundImage.tag`, so then the button could have its own separate tagging system, depending on your uses.

Comment: I thought about that. But I have a endless scroller type thing so when you reach the bottom, it loads more. One idea was giving the ID a decimal, but it just wants to round it

Comment: How do you set a tag for a backgroudImage?

Comment: `button.backgroundImage` is an instance of `UIImage`, so it has a `tag` property. Just do `button.backgroundImage.tag = 0;`

Comment: `Request for member backgroundImage is something not of structure or union`.